# Python - Can not download file from Google Drive using Google Drive API

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-api, google-drive-api

I've been trying to use Google Drive API to automate the download of some files from my Google Drive, choosing to use Python 3.6.5 to do so.

At first, I followd the [quickstart sample](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python) (which worked perfectly) and then moved to the [download files sample](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads), and that was when the headache started. At first, I just "fused" both samples in the below code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from apiclient import discovery
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools
import io
# from oauth2client import client
# from oauth2client import tools

SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly'

def main():


    store = file.Storage('token.json')
    creds = store.get()
    if not creds or creds.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('credentials.json', SCOPES)
        creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
    service = build('drive', 'v3', http=creds.authorize(Http()))

    file_id = 'myfileID'
    request = drive_service.files().get_media(fileId=file_id)
    fh = io.BytesIO()
    downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request)
    done = False
    while done is False:
        status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
        print "Download %d%%." % int(status.progress() * 100)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

But it didn't work, with Python unable to identify **MediaIoBaseDownload**. I then moved on to the following code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from apiclient import discovery
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools
import io
# from oauth2client import client
# from oauth2client import tools

SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly'

def main():


    store = file.Storage('token.json')
    creds = store.get()
    if not creds or creds.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('credentials.json', SCOPES)
        creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
    service = build('drive', 'v3', http=creds.authorize(Http()))

    file_id = 'myfileID'
    request = service.files().get_media(fileId=file_id)

    fh = io.BytesIO()
    with open('mydestinationFile', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(request)

    done = False
    while done is False:
        status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
        print("Download %d%%." % int(status.progress() * 100))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Now getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Google API.py", line 50, in <module>
    main()
  File "Google API.py", line 32, in main
    f.write(request)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'HttpRequest'
```

I googled it, and even searched here on SO, but couldn't find anything similar. I know I'm doing something seriously wrong, but can't tell exactly what.

Comment: Python can't understand what `MediaIoBaseDownload` is because you didn't import it or define it in your first code block. I suggest you don't brute-force this one and instead take it as an opportunity to understand imports and namespaces

Comment: Hey, were you able to the first part working. Meaning, create a token from the credentials?

Comment: Oh, the token part worked pretty well. What's the issue?

Answer (score 1):

`MediaIoBaseDownload` is a method in `googleapiclient.http` class, so you can include the following line in your code to solve this problem:

```
from googleapiclient.http import MediaIoBaseDownload
```

I solve this part of problem, but i still can download the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to download the file you need to change the io.BytesIO usage

**From:**

```
fh = io.BytesIO()
```

**To:**

`fh = io.FileIO("### filename ###", mode='wb')`